# Запятая или тире? 10

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Социальные медиа больше не просто эффективный канал коммуникации () это необходимый компонент успеха вашего бизнеса.*
Филологи, помогите, пожалуйста, с пунктуацией.

Answer (score 1):

Одно тире нужно поставить — перед "это".

Но "больше не просто" — это тихий ужас. Хотя бы уж "теперь не просто".